# HTML form, Firefox "Save Login" lists "Not for display" for username field, which we don't use

Tags: html, forms, firefox

HTML form, Firefox "Save Login" lists "Not for display" for username field, which we don't use.

The best way I thin to show this is the image below:
[image: Firefox save login]

The "create-account" form doesn't even have a "username" field, but we do have an email field.

Is there a way to direct Firefox to not display it this way?  Client believes his customers will freak out, and he could be right.  He knows his clients well.

Another possibility would be to tell Firefox to not try to save login for this form, and let them save from the login page instead.

Comment: Do the input fields use the `autocomplete=off` attribute?

Comment: Look like it is, and removing it doesn't seem to change anything